# NextJs app code changes won't reflect in Docker container

Tags: docker, next.js

I have a dockerized NextJS application. In my local machine, I use volume mapping between my host machine and docker container such that changes to the code especially static html pages are immediately reflected.

```
version: '3'
services:
  next-ui:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./next-ui:/next-ui
      - next_ui_node_modules:/next-ui/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
volumes:
  next_ui_node_modules:
```

However, on a stagging machine, I use a named volume instead as adviced by several forums;

```
version: '3'
services:
  next-ui:
    build:
      context: ./next-ui
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - next_ui_node_modules:/next-ui/node_modules
      - next_ui_next_assets:/next-ui/.next
volumes:
  next_ui_node_modules:
  next_ui_next_assets:
```

My challenge is that upon building the nextjs app container, the css or html made to my static pages is not reflected. I have to delete the container and then the named volume before rebuilding the container and starting it each time I make changes to the code, even if it's just a single line of code. I find this very inefficient.

I know that the contents of the named volume keep replacing the contents of my container's .next directory in every build process.

Is there a workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Delete all of the `volumes:` blocks.  You don't need them at all.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  next-ui:
    build: ./next-ui
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

Imagine that you have a USB thumb drive.  What `volumes:` does, metaphorically, is to plug in that thumb drive and mount it over your application's source code just before you run it.  That means that if you ever change the application code, you also need to change the volume content; as you note, that's inefficient.

Docker has a feature to copy data from the image into volumes, but *only* for Docker named volumes and *only* the first time the volume is used.  Nothing gets copied for bind mounts, or for Kubernetes volumes, or if the image gets updated.  I'd recommend avoiding this feature due to cases like what you're describing in this question.